# Prevent expressjs from sending text in bare response

Tags: express

I am using expressjs to implement api calls for my app.  Much of the time I don't want to send back extra data in the body however expressjs sends the http status text in the response if you don't specify a body.

For `res.send(200);` outputs `OK` in the body, `res.send(400);` outputs `Not Found` and so on.

The problem is that my UI is expecting well formatted JSON or an empty body, and the bare strings break this convention. The work around I've found for now is to send `res.send(200,{});` to send an empty object, but that's a pain in the butt to do that for every api call.

Is there any way to get around express returning this bare text on an empty response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying the express library itself, you can create a middleware function that extends the functionality of `res.send`.

You can modify `res.send` so an empty string is added to its arguments when invoked only with a status code. This will prevent the name of the status code from being sent.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var send = res.send;
  res.send = function() {
    if (arguments.length == 1 && typeof arguments[0] == 'number') {
      arguments[arguments.length++] = '';
    }
    return send.apply(res, arguments);
  };
  next();
});

app.get('/good', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200);
});

app.get('/not-found', function(req, res) {
  res.send(404);
});
```